# c++ malloc segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a problem about malloc(). It is weird.
My code is in the following. 
I use random generator to generate elements for an array.
The array is opened by malloc().
If the array size is smaller than 8192, it is OK. If the size is larger than 8192, it shows segment fault.

```
void random_generator(int num, int * array) {

  srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
  int random_integer; 
  for(int index=0; index< num; index++){ 
    random_integer = (rand()%10000)+1; 
    *(array+index) = random_integer; 
    cout << index << endl;
  } 
}

int main() {
  int array_size = 10000;
  int *input_array;
  input_array = (int*) malloc((array_size));
  random_generator(8192, input_array);    // if the number is larger than 8192, segment fault
  free(input_array);
}
```

Comment: Do you specifically need to use C-style arrays?

Comment: Just a matter of experience.  After a while you develop a reflex to expect sizeof() whenever you see malloc().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`malloc()` takes the size in bytes, not the number of elements.  The size of an `int` is typcially 4 bytes, so you are actually allocating only enough memory for 2500 integers.  You are allocating `array_size` bytes, while you should be allocating `array_size * sizeof(int)` bytes.

So, the error will be fixed by

`input_array = (int*) malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));`

P.S. Never assume that you know the size of an `int` or any other data type, as it is platform dependent.  Always use `sizeof()`.

P.P.S. This is really a C question, rather than a C++ question.  If you are actually using C++, you should consider using `new` and `delete []` instead of `malloc()` and `free()`, or better yet use `std::vector` instead of an array, as Neil pointed out.

Answer (score 11):

You want:

```
input_array = (int*) malloc( array_size * sizeof(int) );
```

you might consider the much simpler:

```
input_array = new int[ array_size ];
// stuff
delete [] input_array;
```

or even:

```
std::vector <int> input_array( array_size );
```

and not have to worry about calling free or delete, or about exceptions.

Comment: Interesting downvote there - which of the above do you think is technically incorrect?

Comment: Maybe they thought you were a bit too radical with your ultra-modern C++ features... `</sarcasm>`

Comment: @Skilldrick Nah - it just looks like one of the clueless is off on another pointless downvoting spree. Hint to the clueless - the SO admin scripts detect this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as its C++ you'd be much better off doing the following:

```
int main() 
{
  int array_size = 8192;
  int *input_array = new int[array_size];
  random_generator(array_size, input_array);
  delete[] input_array;
}
```

Edit: or better still:

```
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
  int array_size = 8192;
  std::vector< int > array;
  array.resize( array_size );
  random_generator(array_size, &array.front());
}
```

And not even worry about the deallocating :D

Answer (score 4):

`input_array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * (array_size));`

It's because the param to malloc is the byte count and int is generally 4 bytes long.

Answer (score 3):

The malloc call you are using is wrong. You should be using:

```
malloc(sizeof(int) * array_size)
```

I think.

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating array_size bytes, but you need array_size integers. Try allocating array_size*sizeof(int) bytes in malloc.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody else has coverted the mistake in dynamic allocation.
But do you really want dynamic allocation?

```
int main() {
  int const array_size = 10000;
  int input_array[array_size];
  random_generator(8192, input_array); 
}
```